# Only return partial list of objects in entity based on query results - spring boot hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have an Event entity which is as follows. Each Event may have a list of EventDetails which is also seen below. (I have kept these objects as simple as possible for explaining purposes)

```java
@Entity(name = "event")
data class Event(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "event_id",
        nullable = false
    )
    val eventDetails: List<EventDetails>
)
```

```java
@Entity(name = "event_details")
data class EventDetails(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    val type: String
)
```

I have a query where I want to return all events which have details of certain types, but more than that, for each event I only want to return the list of details with the provided types - in this case, hibernate returns the full list which isn't what I want.

So I basically want to return the partial list of event details based on what is passed to the query, but the full list of entities are being returned each time. This appears to be because hibernate fetches Events which match the query, and subsequently does an Eager / Lazy fetch of all the EventDetails depending on what I have set, not taking into acount that the query didn't want to return all values of the list.

Here is the query which has highlighted the problem -

```java
@Repository
interface EventRepository : CrudRepository<Event, UUID> {
    @Query(
        """
            select e.* from event e
            join event_details ed on e.id = ed.event_id
            where ed.type in :types
        """, nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun findEventsByDetails(
        @Param("types") types: List<String>
    ): List<AwardEvent>
}
```

Here is an example to highlight the issue. if I have an event as so -

```
Event(eventDetails = listOf(EventDetails(type = "TEST"), EventDetails("OTHER")))
```

and I run the following command -

```
eventRepository.findEventsByDetails(listOf("TEST"))
```

then it should return a list of one Event -

```
Event(eventDetails = listOf(EventDetails(type = "TEST")))
```

without the details including type "OTHER_TEST"

If anyone has any ideas then that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's just how this works. In you specific case, the collection is lazy loaded i.e. your join doesn't matter. In general, entities always reflect the database state as they are mapped. If you filter out elements from a collection, this might cause elements to be removed which you probably don't want. The solution to that is to use DTOs.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Event.class)
public interface AwardEvent {
    @IdMapping
    UUID getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("eventDetails[type IN :types]")
    Set<EventDetailsDto> getEventDetails();

    @EntityView(EventDetails.class)
    interface EventDetailsDto {
        @IdMapping
        UUID getId();
        String getType();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AwardEvent a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AwardEvent.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
@Repository
interface EventRepository : CrudRepository<Event, UUID> {
    fun findAllEvents(
        @OptionalParam("types") types: List<String>
    ): List<AwardEvent>
}
```